# Prove that the linear combination of two vectors is a plane containing the two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you prove that any vector from the linear combination of two vectors forms a plane containing them for two vectors of any dimension?
Can you take the cross product of two vectors and find an equation for their plane and then plug an arbitrary linear combination of the two vector back into that equation to see if it works?

Comment: It depends on what is your definition of a "plane"? Some people may consider the definition of "plane" to be the span of two independent vectors, in which case there is nothing to prove.

Comment: The cross product doesn't really exist in most dimensions, just in 3 or 7 dimensions. There's some info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Generalizations

Comment: No linear combination of $v$ and $-v$ forms a plane. In particular, the vector space generated by the linear combination $v+(-v)$ contains neither $v$ nor $-v$.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is correct. How to prove this depends on how you define "plane" in this context. Since Nick has discussed the vector space meaning, I'll approach it from the geometric side. The first thing that must be done is to establish the vector space - an algebraic object - as a geometric object. For our purposes, this needs a couple definitions:

- *point* = "vector".
- Given any two distinct vectors $v, w$, the *line* through them is the set $\{tv + (1-t)w\mid t \in \Bbb R\}$.

Now we add the geometric definition of a plane:

- A set $A$ of points is *affine* if for any two points in $A$, the entire line through them is a subset of $A$. (Note that the intersection of a collection of affine sets must also be affine.)
- The *affine span* of a set $B$ is the intersection of all affine sets containing it. (Since the entire space is affine, there is at least one.)
- A *plane* is the affine span of three non-collinear points.

And a final definition to recognize that the concept of "vector" is actually more detailed than that of a "point", more closely represented by line segments from a common endpoint:

- The plane *through* two non-parallel vectors $v, w$ is the affine span of $0, v, w$.

Because the vectors are not parallel, the line through $v, w$ cannot contain $0$ (why?). So $0, v, w$ are not collinear, and their span is a plane by the previous definition. Since we are recognizing the "vector-ness" of $v, w$ in this definition, the plane should not just contain the points $v, w$, but the entire line segments. Since it is affine, this only requires that the other endpoint, $0$, also be included.

So for non-parallel $v, w$, let $V = \{ av + bw \mid a,b \in \Bbb R\}$ be their span, and $A$ be their affine span, that is, the plane through $v, w$.

Note that $0 = 0v + 0w \in V$, and if $u_1 = a_1v + b_1w, u_2 = a_2v + b_2w$ are two vectors in $V$, then for any $t \in \Bbb R$,
$$tu_1 + (1-t)u_2 = [ta_1 + (1-t)a_2]v + [tb_1 + (1-t)b_2]w \in V$$
So the entire line through $u_1, u_2$ is also in $V$. Therefore $V$ is an affine set containing $0, v, w$, and so $A \subseteq V$.

Conversely, if $u = av + bw$ with $a+b \ne 0$, then letting $t = \frac a{a+b}$, we see that $u=(a+b)x$ where $x = tv + (1-t)w$. Since $v, w \in A$, so is $x$. Since $0, x \in A$, so is $u$. Also because $0, w \in A$, we have $-w \in A$ as well. Therefore $\frac 12v + \frac12(-w)$ must also be in $A$, and so must be $t(v-w) + (1-t)0$ for any $t$. Since any $u$ as above with $a+b = 0$ has form $a(v-w)$, this means that for all $u \in V, u \in A$.

So $A = V$. The set $V$ of all linear combinations of the two vectors $v, w$ is the same as the plane $A$ through $v$ and $w$.